How to override a url in local.conf / site.conf for a yocto recipie
I am trying to override the url for gstreamer-omx module in yocto recipe.
gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_1.16.3.bb:
SRC_URI = "https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-omx/gst-omx-${PV}.tar.xz"

gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_1.16.3.bbappend
SRC_URI_append = " \
        git://github.com/renesas-rcar/gst-omx.git;branch=RCAR-GEN3e/1.16.3;name=base \
        git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/common;destsuffix=git/common;name=common \
    "

I want to use site.conf to override the urls.
I have tried to use the following in site.conf:
SRC_URI_pn-gstreamer1.0-omx=" \
                                 git://github.com/renesas-rcar/gst-omx.git;branch=RCAR-GEN3e/1.16.3;name=base \
                                 git://github.com/GStreamer/common.git;destsuffix=git/common;name=common \
                            "

However, this did not take effect. Whats is the reason? How do I achieve this?

Most likely cause the original SRC_URI is valid, so no need to fallback. And using site.conf is not the proper way to do it. Stick to the bbappend approach and instead of appending, do overwrite. If still confused use eLBaaS!

I can't use bbappend as its not a repo I can maintain. This project is already very old. I just need something on my end to control the overriding for a few builds.

You can add your own repository with a layer that has a bbappend for gestreamer, does that work for you? Also, does the bbappend you show work? You append to the SRC_URI, so to me it's not instantly clear which of the 3 URLs Yocto would use. It's not custom to change a recipe in local.conf, I'm not sure if it's possible, because SRC_URI wasn't set using ?=. Maybe externalsrc class helps in your use case.

Unfortunately I don't maintain the repo for the meta layer and I don't want a change that requires me to maintain it. I just want to overrride the specific url in local.conf or site.conf.
